# array substitution throwing set -a error

Tags: arrays, shell, unix

I have following piece of code which is working fine if executed standalone -
I am facing a weird error, code is executed fine when executed standalone but throws error when embedded with another piece of code described below in the post

```
date=$1
set -A max_month 0 31 28 31 30 31 30 31 31 30 31 30 31
eval $(echo $date|sed 's!\(....\)\(..\)\(..\)!year=\1;month=\2;day=\3!')
(( year4=year%4 ))
(( year100=year%100 ))
(( year400=year%400 ))
if [ \( $year4 -eq 0 -a \
        $year100 -ne 0 \) -o \
     $year400 -eq 0 ]
then
 set -A max_month 0 31 29 31 30 31 30 31 31 30 31 30 31
fi
day=$((day+1))
echo $day ${max_month[$month]}
if [ $day -gt ${max_month[$month]} ]
then
  day=1
  month=$((month+1))
  if [ $month -gt 12 ]
  then
    year=$((year+1))
    month=1
  fi
fi
new_date=$(printf "%4.4d%2.2d%2.2d" $year $month $day)
echo $new_date

When I try to embed it into following code highlighted in red it throws error, obviously I replaced date=$1 to julian_date_14 -


#!/bin/bash
cd
unset project_env
cd /wload/baot/home/baotasa0/UKRB_UKBE/sandboxes/EXTRACTS/UK/RB/UKBA/ukrb_ukba_pbe_acq
. ab* . >> project_setup.log 2>&1
echo unset the environment is doNe
cd /wload/baot/app/data_abinitio/serial/uk_cust
param1=$1
param2=$2
param3=$3
email=$4
header_date_14=$(m_dump /wload/baot/app/data_abinitio/serial/uk_cust/ukrb_ukba_acnt_bde27_src.dml $param1 | head -35)
hdr_dt_14=$(echo "$header_date_14" | awk '$1=="bdfo_run_date" {print $2}')
julian_date_14=$(m_eval '(date("YYYYMMDD"))( unsigned integer(2)) '$hdr_dt_14'') 2>&1
header_date_15=$(m_dump /wload/baot/app/data_abinitio/serial/uk_cust/ukrb_ukba_acnt_bde27_src.dml $param2 | head -35)
hdr_dt_15=$(echo "$header_date_15" | awk '$1=="bdfo_run_date" {print $2}')
julian_date_15=$(m_eval '(date("YYYYMMDD"))( unsigned integer(2)) '$hdr_dt_15'')
header_date_16=$(m_dump /wload/baot/app/data_abinitio/serial/uk_cust/ukrb_ukba_acnt_bde27_src.dml $param3 | head -35)
hdr_dt_16=$(echo "$header_date_16" | awk '$1=="bdfo_run_date" {print $2}')
julian_date_16=$(m_eval '(date("YYYYMMDD"))( unsigned integer(2)) '$hdr_dt_16'')
echo $julian_date_16
if [ "$julian_date_14" = "$julian_date_15" -a "$julian_date_15" = "$julian_date_16" ]
then
echo all are same
else
echo check the file date please
fi
DATE=`echo $julian_date_14 | cut -c8-9`
Date_minus_1=`expr $DATE - 1`
DATE_1=`echo $julian_date_14 | cut -c2-7`
DATE_FINAL="$DATE_1$Date_minus_1"
echo $DATE_FINAL
```

Error is below -

```
./auto1.sh: line 70: set: -A: invalid option
set: usage: set [-abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option-name] [--] [arg ...]
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: we're not going to dig thru 50+ lines of code to sort this out. Update your Q with a minimal set of code that illustrates the problem. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.